# Getting undefined for $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass data from one controller to another using `$stateParams` but getting null instead of valid data:

Please find my route code below:

```
.state("root.home", {
            url: "/home",
            abstract: true,
            template: homeHtml,
            controller: "HomeCtrl as ctrl",
        })
.state("root.home.content", {
            url: "",
            params: {
                userId: null,
            },
            views: homeView,
        })
```

**Controller A code:**

```
$state.go("root.home.content", {userId}); // getting correct UserId
```

**HomeCtrl code:**

```
// In its constructure I injected the $stateParams

    init() {
            console.log($stateParams); // getting undefined here
            if ($stateParams && $stateParams.userId) {
                this.loadUser($stateParams.userId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you forgot to inject `$stateParams` into the controller?

Comment: Nopes, it is injected.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your parameter as below

```
$state.go("root.home.content", {'userId': userId}); 
//This userId should be a valid variable inside your Controller A
```

And also you should edit your router as below,

```
.state("root.home.content", {
            url: "/:userId",
            params: {
                userId: null,
            },
            views: homeView,
        })
```

Otherwise it will not show in the url & cannot access from $stateParams

Comment: This is probably the reason, I just can't understand why `console.log($stateParams);` is giving them an `undefined`

Comment: I am using ES6 and I think with its property shorthand feature it is not required.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: I am afraid but by doing this will not make any difference as I am injecting params in other controller and handling it in route ("root.home.content"). Not sure but may be I am missing something in the parent route: .state("root.home") as I defined the controller there.

Comment: Yes it was showing correctly but I was not getting null for $stateParams.userId in HomeCtrl

Comment: Glad you got the solution finally

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding params to parent root instead of child. The correct code is:

```
.state("root.home", {
                url: "/home",
                params: {
                    userId: null,
                },
                abstract: true,
                template: homeHtml,
                controller: "HomeCtrl as ctrl",
            })
.state("root.home.content", {
                url: "",
                views: homeView,
            })
```